# batch script: read every file in a directory, replace some strings, shorten each file to 10 lines

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need help writing a batch script on Windows.
My directory C:\OUTFiles contains 2355 .txt files with various lenghts which contain links to Wikipedia articles - for example a file called "Holzhausen.txt":

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/[[Holzhausen (Langenpreising)]], Ortsteil der Gemeinde [[Langenpreising]]
http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/[[Holzhausen (Dähre)]], Ortsteil der Gemeinde [[Dähre]]
...

I would like to go through all files in C:\OUTFiles and cut the lenght of each file to 10 lines (or don't change the lenght if shorter then 10 lines).

Additionally if a file contains [[some text]] like in the first line above I need to remove all brackets [[ ]].

How could I do it as batch script file on Windows?
I am new to batch scripting and I searched StackOverflow and tried to assemble a batch script but it is not quite done/working yet:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set counter=1
for %%f in (*.txt) do call :p "%%f"
goto :eof

:p

SET /A maxlines=10
SET /A linecount=0

FOR /F %%A IN (*.txt) DO ( 
  IF !linecount! GEQ %maxlines% GOTO ExitLoop
  ECHO %%A 
  SET /A linecount+=1
)
SET /A counter+=1


:ExitLoop
:eof
```

PAUSE

Thank you a lot in advance!!
Petra

Comment: `sed` is a Unix tool but there are multiple downloads of Sed for Windows, too.  `sed -i 's/\[\[\([^][]*\)\]\]/\1/g;10q' filename` ... There are different dialects of `sed` so you may need more or fewer backslashes; refer to the documentation for your `sed`.  The `-i` option is not supported by all versions, either.

Comment: PowerShell is a tool that is native to Windows (i.e. you don't have to download it), which is much more capable and powerful than batch.  Strongly suggest you consider writing a powershell script, instead.

Comment: @ tripleee - thank you - I updated the script a bit so it takes every file in a directory:
@ECHO OFF
for %%f in (*.txt) do call :p %%f
goto :eof
:p
sed -i "s/\[\[\([^][]*\)\]\]/\1/g;10q" %1 > tmp; mv tmp %1
goto :eof

Now i still need to fix that it also works with file names containing spaces and dots - like "St. Pölten.txt" or "Wolfsberg im Schwarzautal.txt"

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes that you buy my suggestion above to use powershell instead of batch.

```
# this line assumes current directory - adjust to point to the actual location
$files = get-childitem *.txt
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $data = get-content $file
    $count = 1
    # this assumes that you want to put the modified 
    # output in a new file and keep the original file
    $newfile = $file.name + ".new.txt"
    foreach ($line in $data) {
        if($count -gt 10) {break}
        $line = $line -replace "[\[\]]",''
        out-file -filepath $newfile -inputobject $line -Append
        $count = $count + 1
    }
}
```